# LLVM C++ API bitcode loading and execution

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I am looking for a full sample that covers usage of the LLVM C++ API, particularly loading a function from a bitcode (not a typo, they call it bitcode) file, running it and get the results. I have studied [this blog post](https://pauladamsmith.com/blog/2015/01/how-to-get-started-with-llvm-c-api.html) and I am trying to port it to C++ but I am struggling to understand how to create the various instances needed, particularly the execution engine. I am using `clang -c -emit-llvm file.c` to compile a C file to a `.bc` LLVM bitcode file. The command `clang -S -emit-llvm file.c` also works and generates a textual `.ll` file. The function `parseIRFile` seems to be able to load both.

This is what I have so far:

```c
LLVMContext context;
SMDiagnostic error;
unique_ptr<Module> mod = parseIRFile(StringRef(pathToLlOrBcFile), error, context);
```

I does not have to use JIT, I am fine with the basic interpreter for now; but I wish to make it work with MCJIT or whatever it's called later on.

Thanks to @arnt for noticing that I was actually using the IR text format; I changed the Makefile and the C++ app to reflect the fact that both .ll and .bc can be parsed by the same function.

Comment: You posted an answer yourself at once, but it doesn't load bitcode as far as I can see. Could you clarify? (Also, bitcode really is bitcode, a [bitstream literally consists of a stream of bits](https://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html#primitives).)

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I was working with both .bc and .ll files and ultimately feed a .ll file to my app. Everything works the same with .bc. I'll update the `clang` command to output a bitcode file.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `llvm-devel.x86_64 9.0.1-5.fc31` on Fedora 31. Full code below.

**main.cc** (This is the C++ app that loads the LLVM bitcode)

```c
#include <iostream>

#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h>
#include <llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/GenericValue.h>

using std::unique_ptr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

using llvm::Module;
using llvm::SMDiagnostic;
using llvm::LLVMContext;
using llvm::parseIRFile;
using llvm::StringRef;
using llvm::ExecutionEngine;
using llvm::EngineBuilder;
using llvm::ArrayRef;
using llvm::GenericValue;
using llvm::Function;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  LLVMContext context;
  SMDiagnostic error;
  unique_ptr<Module> mod = parseIRFile(StringRef("hosted.bc" /* .ll files also work */), error, context);
  ExecutionEngine *executionEngine = EngineBuilder(std::move(mod)).setEngineKind(llvm::EngineKind::Interpreter).create();
  Function *add = executionEngine->FindFunctionNamed(StringRef("add"));
  GenericValue param1, param2;
  param1.FloatVal = 5.5;
  param2.FloatVal = 2.7;
  GenericValue params[] = { param1, param2 };
  ArrayRef<GenericValue> args = ArrayRef<GenericValue>(params, 2);
  GenericValue result = executionEngine->runFunction(add, args);
  cout << param1.FloatVal << " + " << param2.FloatVal << " = " << result.FloatVal << endl;
}
```

**hosted.c** (This is a C app that I compile into an `.bc` file with `clang`)

```c
float add(float a, float b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

**Makefile** (Used to compile the native app and the LLVM bytecode to be hosted in it)

```
app.o: main.cc
    g++ main.cc -lLLVM -o app.o

hosted.bc: hosted.c
    clang -c -emit-llvm hosted.c

clean:
    rm app.o
    rm hosted.bc

.PHONY: clean
```

**Output** (Compiling and running)

```
[dario@localhost llvm-cpp-first]$ make hosted.bc && make && ./app.o 
clang -c -emit-llvm hosted.c
g++ main.cc -lLLVM -o app.o
5.5 + 2.7 = 8.2
```

Comment: For me, it leads to `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` at line `ExecutionEngine *executionEngine =  ...`.